# Loading Bearing Post Siting on Top of Base Plate/Rim Joist or on Sill Plate - Need Advice

Tags: framing, load-bearing, post

**Context:** I am working on an addition with a slab on grade. The rest of the house is on a crawl space with a 7.5in step. The step has a still plate on top of the footing footing,  a 2x rim joist siting up, a subfloor, and a base plate on top of the subfloor. I am removing a couple of load bearing walls, and need to add a new 18 ft beam with 4 posts. The post sits right at the step. I have questions on the connection between the post and the bottom plate or the sill plate. See sketch below for reference.

**Questions:**

1. Can the post sit directly on top of the base plate or does it have to go all the way down to the sill plate?
2. If yes, Do I need to add a 2x sitting up right next to the rim joist so that the post sits on a 4x rim joist (to carry load to sill/foundation)?
3. Is it acceptable to cut through the rim joist to allow the post to sit on the sill? ie are there code restrictions on min length of rim joists (I have 4 posts at 5'10 on center)

See detail for reference:

- The slab on grade top elevation is the same as the top of the footing. In my sketch it is not (disregard that), it is an old sketch.
- On the left, I have the post go all the way to the sill. For simplicity of installation, I am looking for feedback on whether it can sit on the base plate instead.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can certainly sit on the walls bottom plate- and you should definitely add support blocking directly under it which goes from the bottom of the plywood subfloor down to the mudsill plate (which sits on the concrete).

This is preferable to cutting through the existing wall bottom plate and rim joist- leave as much integrity to the existing structure as you can. You might consider adding hardware (metal strapping or something like that) to tie the post down to the mudsill plate to lock old to new structure and also give it some uplift resistance.

Comment: Thank you @kyle. If I remove the wall for 2 of the inner posts, there will not be a bottom plate. In this case, the post will sit on the subfloor directly. In that case, what do you suggest?  2 outer posts have a wall bottom plate, the 2 inner posts will not have a bottom plate.

Comment: It is still OK as long as they are supported underneath with solid wood blocks down to the foundation.

Comment: Thank you. What hardware do you recommend?

Comment: @Max - as you've noticed, questions in the comments often get missed. Feel free to ask a whole new question about that, but be sure to carefully phrase it so it doesn't look like you're asking for a product recommendation, as those are explicitly off-topic here.